# Rebuild indexes on InvokeSBFarmUpgrade

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-workflow, workflow-manager-1.x

I have recently followed the steps of upgrading Service Bus 1.0 to Service Bus 1.1.  I am at the step were I am using PowerShell to run "Invoke-SBFarmUpgrade" and the commandlet is failing with:

Invoke-SBFarmUpgrade : Upgrade encountered an exception in upgrade_GatewayDatabase_2.13.0.0_1.7.81.0: Online index operations can only be
performed in Enterprise edition of SQL Server.

I don't see an option in the common parameters to be able to set the rebuild option to offline.  How can I get over this hurdle?

If this isn't possible, can I create a new Service Bus Farm using the configuration wizard and reattach the Workflow manager to the new farm?

Any help would be appreciated.  I'm stuck

Comment: Facing the exact same issue right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open **C:\Program Files\Service Bus\1.1\CommonGatewayStoreUpgrade.sql** and replace `ONLINE = ON` with `ONLINE = OFF`.

Now you can run `Invoke-SBFarmUpgrade` and it will work.

(It's probably a good idea to undo your changes to the *.sql script afterwards)

Comment: You're a god.  I was looking for that for a long time.  Thank you for your help and quick response.

Comment: Hi Daniel. Please accept the answer if it solved your problem. Cheers ;)